# Safe Mode Blue Screen Flash

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, bsod

I have a friends Windows XP HP nc6230 laptop computer which was loaded with spyware and viruses.  She wanted me to "fix it".

When I try to boot "into safe mode with networking" (after hitting F8), the screen starts outputting text to the display, and then part way it flashes to the BSoD and then reboots.

I can boot fine into regular mode, but I want to boot into Safe Mode to run some virus scans and adware scans.

Any idea how I can see what is going on here?  (Logging or something?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text running past is telling you each driver as it is loaded.

You are getting this because one of the safe mode drivers is crashing. Watch the text carefully and note the last name to appear before the BSOD. This will give you a very small clue about where to look (ir you later google the name of the driver file).

Also - suggest you don't use safe mode with networking, the smallest driver set will be plain safe mode.

I know this is only a part answer, it might help you along the way though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately a machine that is loaded with malware will more than likely become a futile battle to try and remove it all. Seeing that malware is the probable cause of the BSoD it would be worth will to reinstall the OS. But to try and answer your question you could try and repair the OS from the recovery console or boot from the Windows XP disc and start the repair process. Hope this helps.